# Generate classes at runtime

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, reflection, code-generation

I have created an Update operation for Linq To Sql (L2S) which works like this:

```
var rowsaffected = db.Tables.Where(...).Join...Group..
                            .Update(x => new Table { Column = x.Something });
```

The problem is that L2S does not allow you to create entities within the query (the line above causes an exception at runtime).

To get around that I create a non-entity class like this:

```
class TableUpdate : Table { }
```

and use it in the Update

```
.Update(x => new TableUpdate { Column = x.Something });
```

which works fine.

The question is now if it is a good idea to create the `TableUpdate` class dynamically at runtime and just replace it in the expression tree before sending it to the L2S sql generator?

The class will never be instantiated so there is no code need, just metadata.

I assume performance is not problem (compared to the actual database update) but are there other thins to think about?

- Can there be name collisions if I create the same class several times?
- Can I cache the metadata?

**Update**

Solved it like this:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> _noEntityClasses = new Dictionary<Type, Type>(1);
private static ModuleBuilder _module;

private static Type CreateNoEntityClass(Type entityClass) {
    lock (_noEntityClasses) {
        Type noentityClass;
        if (!_noEntityClasses.TryGetValue(entityClass, out noentityClass)) {
            if (_module == null) {
                var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("LinqToSqlGenerated");
                var assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
                _module = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("NonEntity");
            }
            var typeBuilder = _module.DefineType(entityClass.Name + "NoEntity", TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.NotPublic, entityClass);
            noentityClass = typeBuilder.CreateType();
            _noEntityClasses.Add(entityClass, noentityClass);
        }
        return noentityClass;
    }
}

private static IQueryable<T> RemoveEntity<T>(IQueryable<T> source, DataContext context) {
    var mapping = context.Mapping.MappingSource.GetModel(context.GetType());
    var noEntityExpression = source.Expression.Visit<MemberInitExpression>(expression => {
            if (!mapping.GetMetaType(expression.Type).IsEntity)
                return expression;
            return Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(CreateNoEntityClass(expression.Type)), expression.Bindings);
                                                          });
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(noEntityExpression);
}
```

Comment: What would be the added benefit over just declaring `TableUpdate`? Would you have to extend from several different `Table`'s or something? P.s.: I don't know about L2S, or the specific problem.

Comment: Each entity you want to update need an `xUpdate` class. The benefit is just avoiding extra classes which might cause confusion or maintenance problems. Also avoids run-time exception surprises if you use the wrong one.

Comment: In that case, yes, I would consider run time code generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [RunSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/runsharp.aspx) you can easily create a new class which extends from an existing one.

You could create a class which creates these wrapped classes and keeps track for which types it already constructed the classes. Probably a `Dictionary<Type, Type>`, linking the original type to the dynamically created wrapped type.

A static function in this class would simply initialize this wrapped type.

```
public static object ExtendedClassInstance<T>()
{
    Type type = typeof( T );
    if ( !_wrappedTypes.Contains( type ) )
    {
        // Use RunSharp to create the type.
    }

    return Activator.CreateInstance( _wrappedTypes[ type ] );
}
```

Comment: @adrianm: RunSharp might have been overkill indeed for your limited use case. I just mentioned it as it's a very interesting library once you start generating more complex classes. :)

Answer (score 0):

A technique I've used is to generate similar classes with a [T4 Template](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/). The link to Oleg's blog has some useful tutorials.

From the problem description, it doesn't sound like you need run-time generation, just compile-time. If you truly need run-time, T4 won't help.

Comment: That wouldn't solve the issue. It would only prevent from having to write the very small `class TableUpdate : Table { }` classes. Probably you need just as much extra information just to get your T4 template to work correctly. The specific queries would still have to know about the specifically generated classes, so it even needs to be a pre-compile step then.